# Rewriting $p(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

We can write $p(A\cup B) = p((A\cup B)\cap S) = p((A\cup B)\cap (B\cup B^{c})) = p((A\cap B^{c})\cup B)$, how has the final step occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the distributive law: $$(A\cap B^c) \cup B = (A\cup B)\cap (B^c\cup B) = (A\cup B)\cap(B \cup B^c)$$

In your problem, we started from above, on the right to obtain the equivalent expression, given above on the left.

(In case you're confused about $S = B\cup B^c$, recall that $B \cup B^c$ is the entire probability space).

Comment: Because the expressions above are all **equal**, we can replace either with the other. It is still an application of the distributive law, which tells us the sets are equivalent. I.e. $P = Q$ means $P = Q$ and/or $Q = P$.